# Displaying RTF in compact framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework, rtf

I have been surfing for this anwser, but seems like its not supportef in CF.

I have come across a solution with SDF InkX control, that can display RTF file.

Can some1 please point me to a good example how to do this?

thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenNETCF InkX is a managed wrapper around the RichInk control, for which there is a fair amount of documentation.  It's also a subset of the desktop RichInk control, so info for the desktop is often applicable.  I'd suggest you start with these:

- [OpenNETCF Samples for the InkX control](http://blog.markarteaga.com/MobileInkLibrarySamples.aspx)
- [RichInk development on Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Wiki/MobileDeveloper/RichInk/)
- [RichInk RTF streaming](http://channel9.msdn.com/Wiki/MobileDeveloper/RichInkRtfStreaming/)